# What is the quickest way to extract entries in a log file between two dates in Python?

Tags: python, date, logging

I have log files with dates and times at different locations in each log file. I want to print entries from the various log files, that are between two dates, to the standard output? For example: I want the entries of the previous 24 hours or I want the entries for the previous week.

What is an efficient way to achieve this in Python?

Kinds Regards, Hendre

Comment: A priori, regex should fit. Vague answer for a vague question

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime

def extract_date(line):
    """Return a datetime from a log line"""
    fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    return datetime.strptime(line.split(' ')[:1], fmt) # make your parser

end_date = date.today()
start_date = start_date - timedelta(days=7))

with open('logfile.log') as f:
    lines = (line for line in f if start_date < extract_date(line) < end_date)
    # ...
    print list(lines)
```

Comment: Will this solution have memory issues when dealing with large files?

Comment: no, it uses generators so only one line will be in memory at a time.

Comment: @elyase: you probably want the example `start_date` to be before the example `end_date` ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop, you are right,:-), fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Your question ringed a bell. From the documentation of [`heapq.merge`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge):

> Merge multiple sorted inputs into a single sorted output (for example,
>   merge timestamped entries from multiple log files). Returns an
>   iterator over the sorted values.

As eyquem said, your question is vague, but once you parse the log files (and possibly normalize them, so they can be sorted together), `heapq.merge` sounds like a good tool.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with a single log file. The aim is to print all log entries to standard output that are between two dates. Here is what I have thus far:

```
import re

startDate="2013-08-31 06:00:00"
endDate="2013-09-01 05:59:59"

date_re = re.compile(r'(\d+-\d+-\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+)')
with open("logfile.log", "r") as fh:
    for line in fh.readlines():
        match = date_re.search(line)
        if match:
           matchDate = match.group(1)
           if matchDate >= startDate and matchDate <= endDate:
               print match.string.strip()
```